# Is it possible to connect to an On-Premise LDAP using the IBM Bluemix Secure Gateway?

Tags: ldap, ibm-cloud

IBM Secure Gateway is a kind of VPN connectivity tool. I need to query an LDAP in an on-premise intranet network.

There is also an another VPN service offered by IBM Bluemix named IPSec.

Which of the two would be more feasible?

Comment: Both. And IBM also offers integration with on-prem LDAP.

Comment: Is there any man page that you can refer here?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of resources your application needs,
if you are using PaaS services (former Bluemix) you can use the Secure Gateway. If you are using IaaS services (baremetal or VMs) than I would suggest Vyatta rather than IPSec, because the latter doen't offer a connecction suitable for production, while Vyatta provides a lot of functionalities among which also an enterprise grade VPN termination bidirectional.

```
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/ipsec-vpn
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/how-configure-ipsec-vyatta
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/03/bluemix-secure-gateway-yes-can-get/
```

Answer (score 0):

I did connect my on-premise ldap to a service hosted on our dedicated instance. I configured destination to ldap server host and port. Our services are deployed on liberty profile so I had to change server.xml for that.

Configuring IPSec VPN is more complicated. I think you should be able to do it using secure gateway

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be a huge help if you can elaborate on the steps? Even abstract steps would work. I'm pretty new to it.